# Error Installing DNS Server Role on Windows 2008 Server. Error Code 0x80070643

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, domain-controller

I'm having a problem adding the DNS server role to my Windows 2008 Server domain controller.  Normally, when I use dcpromo to create a new domain, the DNS service gets installed automatically without error.

However, I'm getting this fatal 0x80070643 error.  It has nothing to do with my network adapters not having an IP address (as stated by Microsoft), since one of my NICs has a static IP.  Has anyone else seen this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Does this KB article apply?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975654